# Android : getting only the last item in the listview multiple times

Tags: android, json, checkbox, android-listview, httpclient

i am trying to get the items in the `listview` using `json` from server, for this i have made my custom adapter. but if there are 6 items on the server it displays the last item 6 times in the list view and i have given a `checkbox` infront of every item in the list to get the id of the checked item. here is my code:

```
btnclub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        ArrayList<Integer> checkedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog d = new Dialog(TennerTextActivity.this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.slctevnt);

            ListView list = (ListView) d.findViewById(R.id.list_mulitple);
            HashMap<String, String> list_map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // Initialize CATEGORY_LIST HERE
            try {
                client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
                        "http://dhklashfgsdhgsdg");
                HttpResponse rp = client.execute(get);
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                System.out.println("----------------------- result: "
                        + result);

                result = "{\"root\": " + result + "}";
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray sessions = root.getJSONArray("root");

                for (int i = 0; i < sessions.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject e = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
                    list_map.put("category_name", e.getString("name"));
                    list_map.put("category_id", e.getString("id"));
                    list_category.add(list_map);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
            d.show();
            Button btndone = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button_multiple);
            btndone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < checkedList.size() ; i++) {
                        clubs = "," + String.valueOf(checkedList.get(i));
                    }
                    clubs = clubs.substring(1);
                    System.out.print(clubs);
                    Log.e("club", clubs);
                }
            });
```

and my adapter is:

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list_category.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglist,
                            null);
                    TextView item = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogitem);
                    item.setText(list_category.get(position).get(
                            "category_name"));


                }
                CheckBox check = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_list);
                check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(isChecked) {
                            int temp = Integer.parseInt(list_category.get(position).get("category_id"));
                            checkedList.add(temp);
                            Object[] tempArray = checkedList.toArray();
                            Arrays.sort(tempArray);
                            checkedList.clear();
                            for(int i = 0 ; i < tempArray.length ; i++) {
                                checkedList.add((Integer) tempArray[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }

        }
```

please tell where i am doing wrong ...

Comment: in getItem(int position) return position instead of null

Comment: initialize checkbox inside if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem** is in below line

```
                   list_map.put("category_name", e.getString("name"));
                    list_map.put("category_id", e.getString("id"));
                    list_category.add(list_map);
```

you are putting `category_name` and id into `list_map` and adding same into `list_category`. here you are adding list_map instance in list_category. and becuse of the key for map(which is category_name and id ) is same,

*it can store only one value corresponding to one key, hence it is storing last inserting value of these keys.*

when you are updating list_map with new data the instance itself getting change), That is why it is showing 6 times of last list_map data.

**Solution** : what you can do here, initialize list_map in loop only with new keyword, so it will insert new instance every-time you insert into list_category. or you can use two d array. instead of hashmap.

```
HashMap<String, String> list_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

*P.S: I pointed out one problem in your code, which is causing duplicacy of data, there can be other problem also as suggested by other SO members.*

**Edit:**
replace your below code

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < checkedList.size() ; i++) {
                        clubs = "," + String.valueOf(checkedList.get(i));
                    }
                    clubs = clubs.substring(1);
```

with something like below

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0 ; i < checkedList.size() ; i++) {
                       sb.add(String.valueOf(checkedList.get(i))+",");
                    }
                 sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
```

Comment: yeah i am getting all the items in the `listview` now but there is still one problem, it returns id of only the last checked item like if i check `1,2,3` it returns 3 and if i check `3,4` it returns 4...

Comment: if you select multiple checkboxes, you need to check all one by one, and store which one is checked or not

Comment: yeah i want to check multiple checkboxes and get their ids in a string seperated by commas..example..`1,2,5`

Comment: are you doing this in btnDone onClick?? let me know

Comment: `The method add(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder` this is the error i am getting at `sb.add(String.valueOf(checkedList.get(i))+",");`

Comment: u can use append, replace add with append

Comment: hey whenever i click on the button the items gets added again to the list..like first time when i click it shows 4 items and next time when i click it shows 8 items  `4 items gets repeated`...please tell how do i remove this..

Comment: Remove all items before u insert new items.. u can dosomethibg like list.clear

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to change for loop like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sessions.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
 HashMap<String, String> list_map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        JSONObject e = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
                        list_map.put("category_name", e.getString("name"));
                        list_map.put("category_id", e.getString("id"));
                        list_category.add(list_map);

                    }
```

Comment: i am getting all the items in the listview now but there is still one problem, it returns id of only the last checked item like if i check 1,2,3 it returns 3 and if i check 3,4 it returns 4.

Answer (score 0):

change `getView` methode like this

```
if (convertView == null) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglist,null);
}

TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialogitem);
item.setText(list_category.get(position).get("category_name"));
```

Comment: use my solutions with @Sanket Kachhela's solution.